# Big O notation calculation for nested loop

Tags: c++, algorithm, time, big-o

```
for ( int i = 1; i < n*n*n; i *= n ) {
    for ( int j = 0; j < n; j += 2 ) { 
        for ( int k = 1; k < n; k *= 3 ) { 
            cout<<k*n;
        }
    }
}
```

I am facing an issue with this exercise, where I need to find the big O notation of the following code, but I got `O(n^5)` where the first loop is `n^3`, 2nd loop n, and the 3rd loop is `n` and I am not sure if I am correct or not. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your analysis is **not** correct.

*The outer loop* multiplies i by n each ietration,starting from 1 till n^3.
Therefore there will be 3 iterations which is **O(1)**.

*The middle loop* increments j by 2 each iteration, starting from 0 till n.
Therefore there will be n/2 iterations which is **O(n)**.

*The inner loop* multiplies k by 3, from 1 till n.
Therefore there will be log3(n) iterations, which is **O(log(n))**.
If this step is not clear, see here: [Big O confusion: log2(N) vs log3(N)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20512642/big-o-confusion-log2n-vs-log3n).

**The overall time complexity** of the code is a multiplication of all the 3 expressions above (since these are nested loops).

**Therefore is it:** O(1) * O(n) * O(log(n)), i.e.: **O(n*log(n))**.

Answer (score 1):

First loop is i=1 and every time multiplies by n until its n^3 so its 3 times, which is O(1).
Second loop is j=1 and every time added 2 until its n so its n/2 times, which is O(n).
Third loop is k=1 and multiplies by 3 until its n, which is O(log(n))
Overall: O(n*log(n))

Answer (score 0):

You are not correct. In first loop `for ( int i = 1; i < n*n*n; i *= n )` pay attention to "statement 3"(`i *= n`), and in third loop `for ( int k = 1; k < n; k *= 3 )` also pay attention to "statement 3"(`k *= 3`). Your calculation for second loop is great.

Comment: is it log n and log n? Just found out what is *= += -= xD

Comment: The second loop will iterate n/2 times, in big O notation, it will be O(n). The first loop will iterate 3 times which is O(1), and the third loop will iterate log3(n) times which is O(log3(n)). So total time complexity is O(1)*O(n)*O(log3(n)) which is O(n*log3(n)).

Comment: @Q_i99i If you don't even know what the code does, then why do you try to analyze its complexity? That can't work. Learn the basics of the language first.

Comment: Its a complexity exercise